# Sorting parent menu items in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I have a menu, with multiple :parent items.
With :priority I can sort the items within a drop down menu.

How can I sort my main menu parent items?
I'm using the latest version of activeadmin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I helped myself with a hack, I found:

If you drop the following into the setup block of config/initializers/active_admin.rb.

It uses the priority of the first displayable child menu item to indicate the sort priority for the parent item.

```
  class ::ActiveAdmin::Views::TabbedNavigation
    def priority_for(item)
      child_item = item.children.detect { |child| display_item?(child) }
      child_item ? child_item.priority : item.priority
    end
    private :priority_for

    # Returns an Array of items to display
    def displayable_items(items)
      items.select do |item|
        display_item? item
      end.sort { |i1, i2| priority_for(i1) <=> priority_for(i2) }
    end
  end
```

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve the same within the default active admin initializer, no hacking required:

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.build_menu do |menu|
    menu.add label: "My first item", priority: 1
    menu.add label: "My second item", priority: 2
    menu.add label: "My third item", priority: 3
  end
end

# config/initializers/active_admin.rb
```

Comment: this is the method suggested on https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html

Answer (score 0):

on ActiveAdmin v=0.4.4 this little modified Version worked for me as an initializer:

```
class ::ActiveAdmin::Views::TabbedNavigation
  def priority_for(item)
    item.children.map(&:priority).min || item.priority
  end

  private :priority_for

  def menu_items
    menu.items.sort { |i1, i2| priority_for(i1) <=> priority_for(i2) }
  end
end
```