# How to set a parent menu priority in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a couple of models in my Ruby on Rails application like "Plan", "Tester", "Module", etc. Using activeadmin gem, I would like to have a page for each of these entities and place each under a couple of different menus. So my code looks like the following:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Plan do
  menu parent: 'Planning', priority: 1

ActiveAdmin.register Tester do
  menu parent: 'Planning', priority: 2

ActiveAdmin.register Module do
  menu parent: 'Bundle', priority: 1

ActiveAdmin.register User do
  menu parent: 'Administration', priority: 1
```

I don't have a page for the top menus ('Planning', 'Bundle', 'Administration'), but I want to see them in a custom order and not the alphabetical order. So, my question is how could I set the priority (order) of the parent menus without having a corresponding page for each of them?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910416/sorting-parent-menu-items-in-activeadmin?rq=1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The items, which non model-based starts their priority from 10, so u can put 10+ priority for model-based menus.
If you need to set priorities among non model-based menus, you can build fake file under admin folder like admin/administration.rb with code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Administration" do
  menu :label => "Administration", :priority => 15, :url => '#'
end
```

and admin/bundle.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Bundle" do
  menu :label => "Bundle", :priority => 16, :url => '#'
end
```

so on

Comment: Should I have a separate file for each? The file name should be singular or plural?

Comment: You can name file whatever you want, and yes, you can use them in 1 file.

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand the first sentence in your answer. What you say is *non-model-based* items START their priority from10. And then you say one can use a priority for *model-based* items up from 10. That is the same ... ??? Can you clarify this a bit? Thank you.

Comment: Your item, which have no page/model (Like "Administration" page of topic-starter) is fake (non-model-based). And that items, which have model (real pages) is model-based.

Comment: I mean, if you don't create a fake item like I described, then priority of that item will be 10+, but if you create fake, you can handle set priority to it

Answer (score 9):

See 'Customizing Parent Menu Items' in the [documentation](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#customize-the-menu).

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.build_menu do |menu|
    menu.add label: 'Blog', priority: 0
  end
end

# app/admin/post.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  menu parent: 'Blog'
end
```